# Git on Mac: Undefined symbol "locale_charset"

Tags: xcode, macos, git

Completely out of the blue this morning, the git on my mac laptop stopped working.  I'm getting the error:

```
$ git pull origin master
/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-shell: Undefined symbol "locale_charset"
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm running OSX 10.9.5.

I've seen some solutions for bsd using ports, but does anyone know how to resolve this on OSX? Is it possible to completely reinstall xcode's command line tools, and would that relink everything properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, turns out the error was on the remote server.  Upgrading bash to fix shellshock screwed up a lot of programs.

The remote server needed to upgrade its git install. Afterwards everything functioned properly